# PHP Bulk Emailing

Tags: php, email, bulk

With PHP, i figured out that, using `mail()` (following example) is not a formal way for bulk emailing.

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    mail($email, $subject, $message);
}
```

So which method or package will be most suitable one?

Comment: How many is 'bulk'? That is a relative term around here..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bulk emailing"?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into professional solutions like ConstantContact or MailChimp.  These guys are built to do this, and are very aware of the lower level things that go on for bulk-emailing.

Then again, you could set up a dedicated server to do this as well, these are typically called "Email Blasters".

Comment: Dedicated servers aren't the best way to go. Email is all about reputation. If you don't have a reputable source, you are going to end up on the blacklists before you can bat an eyelid.

Comment: VerticalResponse is another good one. However, all these services price differently, so shop around!

Comment: I never said that they were the best way to go.  I said it more as an after thought, and recommended that he go with professional solutions.

Comment: I've used Mailchimp for years - they are probably the best of the email marketing services - best pricing, best UI, best list management, etc. - Also look into iContact and Streamsend --- at my job where we had to send out lots of blasts (hundreds per year for a publishing company) we actually got kicked off MailChimp for not adhering to their list rules. They all work basically the same though - server reputation is key, and this is what these people do.

Comment: Guys please, are the MailChimp/ iContact/ StreamSend the Code Packages?? I hope they are just the services, not opensource. Because i have to control the mail sending programmatically in my site.